# What does the is_your_order field mean in a btc-e response?

Tags: api, btce

Their amazing API documentation (https://btc-e.com/api/documentation) shows a field called `is_your_order`. Not sure what it means and they certainly don't explain it.

Does anyone know?

Comment: is_your_order = 0 does not mean the order is not yours.
it does not mean it's a part of a split order too.
I had only one record in transhistory and tradehistory.
so, its weird and does not seem logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field indicates that the order is yours with a value of `1`. With a `0`, it indicates it is not an order made by you.

It's indeed nowhere documented, the only valid arguments for my explanation are the name of the variable and the fact that I can only find `0` or `1` values for it.

(I found [this piece of code](https://github.com/kushti/btce-scala/blob/master/btce-trade.scala#L130) where they save `the is_your_order` field as a boolean, testing of the value `==1`.)

Comment: If it's an order not made by me, then why would it be in my trade history?

Comment: Perhaps there's also an option to show trade history from all the market.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, is_your_order is used when their system doesn't fill the orders right away and their system generates new orders for smaller amounts to split up your original order into multiple new orders. For instance, I put in a sell order for 1btc. In my trade history, I see 3 transactions related to that single order:

```
  { pair: 'btc_usd',
  type: 'sell',
  amount: 0.441969,
  rate: 7.7,
  order_id: 87505,
  is_your_order: 0,
  timestamp: 126 }

  { pair: 'btc_usd',
  type: 'sell',
  amount: 0.16,
  rate: 7.672,
  order_id: 87402,
  is_your_order: 0,
  timestamp: 126 }

  { pair: 'btc_usd',
  type: 'sell',
  amount: 0.398031,
  rate: 7.54,
  order_id: 87208,
  is_your_order: 0,
  timestamp: 127 }
```

I've modified the numbers to lose some precision to mask my transaction information a bit, but if you notice, the order_id's are different and so are the rates!